# ADB will not run

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, adb

I just installed the android SDK with eclipse, straight from google's webpage, but for some reason it won't run, even when I am in the correct directory. When I use 'ls' (crunchbang linux) it show's that the file is there, but when I try to run it, it returns no such file or directory. Any ideas?

Comment: try putting "./" before adb.   That is type "./adb"

Comment: If that doesn't work, we'll need more information. What command are you trying to run? What is the output of `ls`?

Answer (score -1):

type script in your command if you adb configured.

1. `adb stop-server`
2. `adb start-server`
3. `adb devices`